What are signs your high school algebra II (arithmetic) course plan focuses heavily on the first half and neglects depth in the second half?
What are signs your algebra II course plan focuses heavily on the first half and skimmed the second half?

I'm trying to figure out whether I'm going evenly.

I'm trying to figure out whether students taking my class need to be advised you'll have to do college algebra simultaneously with pre-calculus because I'm not going hard enough on the topics in the second half.

If I can't find evidence, I suspect the students who feel a need to be labelled as smart will just assume they're dumb if they do revise the material and will try to learn calculus not knowing how some basic foundation works.


In general how can you tell whether you course plan is balanced? covers every topic equally deep?
I don't know how to come up with a infinite sequence of successive ways to write out a problem that gets harder and harder on any specific topic.

A suggestion: you'll get far more helpful answers if you post a link to your actual course plan.

Look at the schedule and see if the pace matches the textbook.
